# With redux-form v7.2.0, how to autoSubmit on radio button selection?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a redux-form which has one field which asks the user to make a radio button selection. Once the user selects a radio button, I want the form to instantly-submit without the user having to click the submit button.

What is the correct way to auto-submit a form using redux-form v7.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

In the radio `onChange` on `onBlur` callback you could setup a dispatch in the same way as remote submit is done: https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/remotesubmit/